# can there be 'cross-referencing' generators in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, generator

Imagine the following piece of code which generates a list of file sizes from the current directories' files:

```
_sizes = []
for _base, _dirs, _files in os.walk('.'):
    for _file in _files:
        _size = getsize(join(_base, _file))
        _sizes.append(_size)
```

I wonder whether I can create a nested generator from this - s.th. like:

```
_sizes = [getsize(join(_base, _file)) 
              for _file in _files 
                  for [_base, _dirs, _files in os.walk('.')]]
```

This is syntactically incorrect of course since `[_base, _dirs, _files in os.walk('.')]` is not correct generator syntax. What I need now is a way to iterate through a sub-element from a list (`_files`) while referencing another one (`_base`) (what I called cross-referencing in the title).

I now wonder if I just can't see the obvious or if this is approach is not valid in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
_sizes = [
    getsize(join(_base, _file))
    for _base, _dirs, _files in os.walk('.')
    for _file in _files
]
```

If you want generator, use generator expression (replacing `[]` with `()`):

```
_sizes = (
    getsize(join(_base, _file))
    for _base, _dirs, _files in os.walk('.')
    for _file in _files
)
```

See [list comprehension in Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following structure :

```
_sizes = [ getsize(join(_base, _file)) for _base, _dirs, _files in os.walk('.') for _file in _files ]
```

And note that you don't need to put the first loop within `[]` since you can use nested `for` loops within a list comprehension.